# recursively adding to list with pairs haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to add the list of pairs I have into a single list.
For example if I had the pairs:

```
[(2,0),(4,5),(3,10)]
```

Notice each pair is a (value, index)
I would want:

```
[2,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,3]
```

so far I have:

```
insert :: [(Int,Int)] -> Int -> [Int]
insert []                _ = [] 
insert ((x, y):xs) t
  | t == y = x : (insert (xs) (t + 1))  
  | otherwise = 0     : insert ([(x,y)]) (t + 1)
```

and I am only getting

```
[2,0,0,0,0,0,4]
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: This looks like a very similar question that you asked recently.

Comment: @FrancisKing Yes, but it's incorporating the answer from that question. I think this is what we ask people to do: if you get partway to a solution and have a new question, ask a new Question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code is that the rest of the list is thrown away when `otherwise = 0     : insert ([(x,y)]) (t + 1)` is done. The remainder `xs` is lost.

There are two recursions happening here:

1. Recursion over elements in the list
2. Recursion to add the current element

So, I recoded it to add one element:

```
lst:: [(Int,Int)]
lst = [(2,0),(4,5),(3,10)]

insertOne :: (Int,Int) -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
insertOne (x, y) t out
   | t == y = out ++ [x] 
   | otherwise = insertOne (x,y) (t + 1) (out ++ [0])
```

Also to add all of the elements:

```
 insertList :: [(Int, Int)] -> [Int] -> [Int]
 insertList [] target = target
 insertList (x:xs) target =
     insertList xs (insertOne x (length target) target)
```

That seems to work, provided that the input list is ordered by index.

```
 insertList lst []  -- [2,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,3]
```